# The solution $X$ of the SDE $\mathrm d X_t = f(t, X_t) \mathrm d t + g(t, X_t) \mathrm d B_t$ is a Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm reading Section 5.4 *Markov property* from these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf), i.e.,

---

$\newcommand{\Ex}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\diff}{\,\mathrm d}$Let $B$ be a standard Brownian motion and $(\mathcal F_t, t \ge 0)$ its natural filtration. Let $f, g:\mathbb R_{\ge 0} \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be jointly continuous in $(t, x)$ and Lipschitz in $x$. Let $X$ be the strong solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
\diff X_t &= f(t, X_t) \diff t + g(t, X_t) \diff B_t, \\
X_{0} &= x_0.
\end{cases}
\quad (\star)
$$

Let $h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be bounded continuous. It can be shown that if $T \ge t \ge 0$ then
$$
\Ex [h(X_T) | \mathcal F_t] = \varphi (X_t) = \Ex [h(X_T) | X_t],
$$
where $\varphi (x) := \Ex [h(X^{t, x}_T)]$ with $X^{t, x}$ the strong solution of
$$
\begin{cases}
\diff X_s &= f(s, X_s) \diff s + g(s, X_s) \diff B_s, \quad \forall s \in [t, T],\\
X_t &= x.
\end{cases}
$$

---

It's mentioned in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/304882/368425) that if $X$ is time-homogeneous then $X$ is a Markov process.

> Could you elaborate on the proof or the references that the solution $X$ of $(\star)$ is a Markov process?

Comment: A reference: Schilling, Partzsch, Boettcher; Th.18.13. p. 285

Comment: @Snoop This is exactly what I have been looking for. Could you post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reference for the result: [Schilling, Partzsch, Boettcher](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110278989/html?lang=en); Th.18.13. p. 285.

---

One can consult also the newer edition: [Schilling](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110741278/html?lang=en); Th.21.23. p. 403.